# How to Pandas pivot tables in both ascending and descending orders together?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, pivot-table

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Country':["AU","GB","KR","US","GB","US","KR","AU","US"],'Region Manager':['TL','JS','HN','AL','JS','AL','HN','TL','AL'],'Campaign Stage':['Start','Develop','Develop','Launch','Launch','Start','Start','Launch','Develop'],'Curr_Sales': [453,562,236,636,893,542,125,561,371],'Curr_Revenue':[4530,7668,5975,3568,2349,6776,3046,1111,4852],'Prior_Sales': [235,789,132,220,569,521,131,777,898],'Prior_Revenue':[1530,2668,3975,5668,6349,7776,8046,2111,9852]})
pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Curr_Sales', 'Curr_Revenue','Prior_Sales','Prior_Revenue'],index=['Country', 'Region Manager','Campaign Stage'],aggfunc=np.sum,margins=True)
```

[image]
I have the above df and the pivot table for the outputs. I'd like to sort the pivot table first by the "Campaign Stage" ascending order (Start-Develop-Launch) and then by the Curr_sales descending order.

Also, how would I add subtotals for each Country?

Comment: you may want to add code instead of pictures, it will help others recreate your problem/solution

Comment: The code is provided at the top of the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `sort_values` with both columns:

```
piv_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Curr_Sales', 'Curr_Revenue','Prior_Sales','Prior_Revenue'],
                     index=['Country', 'Region Manager','Campaign Stage'],
                     aggfunc=np.sum,margins=True)


piv_df.sort_values(['Campaign Stage', 'Curr_Sales'], ascending=[True, False])

piv_df
                                       Curr_Revenue  Curr_Sales  \
Country Region Manager Campaign Stage                             
All                                           39875        4379   
GB      JS             Develop                 7668         562   
US      AL             Develop                 4852         371   
KR      HN             Develop                 5975         236   
GB      JS             Launch                  2349         893   
US      AL             Launch                  3568         636   
AU      TL             Launch                  1111         561   
US      AL             Start                   6776         542   
AU      TL             Start                   4530         453   
KR      HN             Start                   3046         125
```

you can see a solution for the subtotals in this post [pandas subtotals on groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494720/python-pandas-subtotals-on-groupby)